# How to make crash reporting for a cordova app with firebase as database

Tags: cordova, firebase, cordova-plugins, firebase-crash-reporting

I want to use firebase crash reporting for simple cordova app which is basically made of simple HTML, javascript and css.

It gives me error the following error

> "the connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file ///android_asset/www/index.html)"

There is no such study material on internet, please share the inputs.

Comment: Firebase Crash Reporting only supports native Android and iOS apps.

Comment: This plugin says it supports Crash Reporting too. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-sdk